# How to prove that the 4-coloring problem is NP-complete

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, np-complete

I know that the 4-coloring problem is NP-complete, but I'm looking for a proof of that statement. Unfortunately, I haven't found a (for me) reasonable and clear proof.

I tried to reduce the 4-coloring problem to the 3-coloring problem and since that is NP-complete, the 4-coloring problem would be NP-complete. Still, I haven't found a solution for that. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: If you want to prove 4-coloring is NP-complete and you know 3-coloring is, then you should go the other way around: reduce 3-coloring to 4-coloring. Hint: add one vertex.

Answer (score 4):

For every fellow person who is struggeling with the same proof, I came up with this solution:
I created a 3 color tree. Then I added a vertex like [Michal-Adamaszek](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/537646/michal-adamaszek) proposed (thanks for the hint). Next I draw an edge from each of my 3 colored Graphs vertices to the new vertex. Since every color is connected to the new vertex, this vertex needs a new 4th color.Nevertheless, this 4 colored Graph can only be colored correctly, if the original 3 colored Graph is colored correctly. Therefor I reduced the 3 colore problem to a 4 color problem. Does this make sense? It would help me and others a lot if somebody could confirm my thoughts.[image: Proof of 4 coloring problem]

Comment: Yep, this works. If you had an algorithm to solve 4-coloring, you could use it to test if a graph $G$ is 3-colorable, by adding a vertex adjacent to all others and testing if the new graph $G'$ is $4$-colorable. Since 3-colorability is NP-complete, all NP problems can be reduced to 3-coloring, and then we can use this strategy to reduce them all to 4-coloring.

Comment: Technically, you should also prove that 4-colorability is in NP; this only proves that it's NP hard. The argument is the same as the argument that 3-colorability is in NP.

Comment: Well, to show that 4-colorability is in NP, I have to check in $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ time if  the end points of every edge have different colours. But since there are a lot of algorithm for searching in a graph (DFS for example) with a complexity less than $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ (DFS has $\mathcal{O}(V+E)$) I think it is very obvious that the 4-colorability is in NP.

Comment: $O(n^2)$ is not necessary - any polynomial will do. I agree that it's not hard to check this, but it needs to be shown to have a complete argument.

Comment: Isn't that proven by saying I can DFS the graph and DFS has allways polynomial complexity?

Comment: I'm not sure "DFS" rather than "just check all edges one at a time" is the best way to go, but yes, that does finish the proof.